# Behavior of stdin.readByteSync() method in Dart Lang

Tags: flutter, dart, math, operators

I'm trying to run the simplest operation in Dart just to test the operators and this input method, but the result is strange for me. I started to study dart recently.
Here is the code:

```
import 'dart:io';
main(){
    int a = 10;
    int b = stdin.readByteSync();

    print(a + b);
}
```

When the input is the number 1, for example, it returns me the number 59. I read the documentation, but nothing explained me the because of this result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because ASCII CODE of 1 is 49,  ASCII CODE of 2 is 50
When you input 1, you will get 59, when you input 2 you will get 60

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  int a = 10;
  int b = stdin.readByteSync();
  print(b);
  print(a + b);  
}
```

[image]

code snippet with `stdin.readLineSync`

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  int a = 10;
  String b = stdin.readLineSync();
  int c = int.parse(b);
  print(c);
  print(a + c);  
}
```

working demo with `stdin.readLineSync`

[image]

Comment: So the readByteSync() method always converts the input to its ASCII format? Shoud I use the readLineSync() method instead to input a value even for numbers?